# Long Running task is failing in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index of ~180 million documents (I have 34 of them to be clear) that I'm currently transforming in ElasticSearch using /reindex and _ingest/pipeline.

And the thing is that it's failing 80% of the runs. With this error:

```
"error" : {
"type" : "search_phase_execution_exception",
"reason" : "all shards failed",
"phase" : "query",
"grouped" : true,
"failed_shards" : [
  {
    "shard" : -1,
    "index" : null,
    "reason" : {
      "type" : "illegal_state_exception",
      "reason" : "node [d6UWyUAKSwq53szZy2VlNQ] is not available"
    }
  }
]
```

It usually happens in 120-140 million documents. Looking in Grafana - everything seems fine. CPU load is good, memory is enough. And I can't figure out what can be done to save time, instead of launching that procedure again and again.

Example of run:

```
POST /_reindex?wait_for_completion=false&slices=auto
{
  "source": {
    "index": "index_tmp"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "index_resulting",
    "pipeline": "remove_unused_fields"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, have you been through this "checklist" https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/ec-nodes-unavailable-missing.html

Comment: You should try with `slices=1` to put less load on your cluster

Comment: Thanks for you responses! I will rerun the task and get back to you with updates.

Comment: also what do the logs on the node that was marked as unavailable say?

Comment: Hi @Val, thanks! Seems like setting slices=1 worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You should try with slices=1, it will take longer, but it will also put less load on your cluster

```
POST /_reindex?wait_for_completion=false&slices=1
{
  "source": {
    "index": "index_tmp"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "index_resulting",
    "pipeline": "remove_unused_fields"
  }
}
```